# Interface pointer as a function argument

Tags: pointers, go

This most likely stems from a misunderstanding of what interface{} is in go. I have the following code

```
type Configuration struct {
    Username string
}

func loadJson(jsonStr []byte, x *Configuration}) {
    json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, x)
}

func main() {
    //var config *Configuration
    config := new(Configuration)
    file, e := ioutil.ReadFile("config.json")
    loadJson(file, config)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", config.Username)
}
```

It loads a json configuration into the config variable. I want to make the loadJson function more abstract and accept any struct. I thought the best way to do that would be to accept a `*interface{}`, however I get the following error when changing the loadJson Signature.

```
 ./issue.go:30: cannot use config (type *Configuration) as type *interface {} in argument to loadJson:
*interface {} is pointer to interface, not interface
```

Instead load json should be this

```
func loadJson(jsonStr []byte, x interface{}}) {
    json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, x)
}
```

Is interface{} already a pointer? Also the error message doesn't make the most sense to me, isn't configuration a pointer to an interface? Also, if I change `json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, x)` to `json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &x)` it will work perfectly fine still. What is going on here that allows that to work?

Side question but relevant to pointers, why can't I declare a pointer like the commented out line(under main)?

Comment: Try `json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, *x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use interface{} to represent any type including pointers:

```
func loadJson(jsonStr []byte, x interface{}) {
   json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, x)
}
```

<kbd>[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/D6nTefNMP5)</kbd>

Although you can assign a `Configuration` to an `interface{}`, the memory layout of a `Configuration` value and an `interface{}` value are different. Because the memory layouts are different, a pointer to an `interface{}` cannot be converted to a pointer to a `Configuration`. The [same reasoning applies to a `[]T` and a `[]interface[}`](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface).

[It's rare to user a pointer to an interface in Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface).

Regarding the side note: You can use a variable declaration and assignment

```
var config *Configuration
config = new(Configuration)
```

or you can use a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
config := new(Configuration)
```

You cannot use declaration and short declaration together because it declares the variable twice.

Answer (score 2):

> Is interface{} already a pointer?

No, not in general <sup>[1]</sup>.

> What is going on here that allows that to work?

Consider the following type definition:

```
type Number int
```

`int` and `Number` are now two completely distinct types. You [can't](http://play.golang.org/p/EbGCn8F7op) use a `*int` where a `*Number` is expected; even if they are essentially the same, even memory-wise.

The rule is the same for `*Configuration` and `*interface{}`; even if their memory representation was identical (which it isn't).

Why does it work for `interface{}` then? Because interface-types are special; they are Go's way of doing polymorphism. Any value can be "boxed" in an interface value if it implements said interface.

<sup>[1] Under the hood, an interface value sometimes holds a pointer but that's an implementation detail and not relevant here.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A pointer to an interface has a different memory layout than a pointer to a Configuration. They are not interchangeable and you can't use *interface{} to represent any pointer. Think of an interface value like a box. The idea is you want to pass the json function a box containing a pointer and not a pointer to a box.

If you want to understand the underlying representation of an interface, see http://research.swtch.com/interfaces.